# Create and show a WPF window from a Module, with PRISM

Tags: wpf, multithreading, c#-4.0, prism

I've got an application that uses PRISM, and one of my requirements is to show a popup window (not a dialog) when certain events occur in the back-end (more precisely, in a Service (the kind of service that you inject in the viewmodel)).

I'd tried to use the creating of a threat (a STAThread) but doesnt work).

Is there a way to attach the newly created window to the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

Using Prism’s InteractionRequests, view models can make interaction requests (such as notifications or confirmations) to the view. This can be hooked up to a service notification handler.

Please see http://www.dominikschmidt.net/2011/03/netc-prism-interactionrequests-in-wpf/ for more details and example code to get you going.

Comment: Tnx so much for the advise. I looked at your solution and seems quite complex (at least for me). So, I managed to use the Dispatcher and a delegate in the BeginInvoke method with a direct call to the RequestNavigate and it worked like a charm.